# how to generate asp validation control from behind?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-4.5

i am wondering about asp validation control, let say we are building an asp application and integrating it with an external social medias such as : Facebook, LinkedIn, etc. and get some data from there, then we use the data and fill it into some fields or control, due to uncertain amount of data that returned from those medias, we decide to generate control like text box from behind, depend on the amount of data that returned, my question is how about validation? can we generate asp validation control from behind too?
if it is possible, show me some example, any help would be great, thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure You Can! getting data from social media like Facebook or LinkedIn is related to getting response for `POST` or `GEt` call.

For example set one of your variables like:

```
 mail = Response.Write(Request.Form['mail']);
```

Or if You have it already in text box simply:

```
string email = TextBox1.Text;
```

and then You can run for example `regex` validator:

```
Regex regExEmail = new Regex(@"^(((((0[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8]))-((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])))|((31-((0[13578])|(1[02])))|((29|30)-((0[1,3-9])|(1[0-2])))))-((20[0-9][0-9])|(19[0-9][0-9])))|((29-02-(19|20)(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))))$ ");
if (!regExEmail.IsMatch(email))
{
    Response.Write("not valid");
}
```

For adding textbox dynamically check [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/355847/how-to-create-dynamic-textbox-dropdown-list-in-asp)

If u want example in `VB` try [this](http://www.iowawebnet.com/ein/2013/01/validate-date-in-code-behind-with-regex-vb-net/)

Comment: thank you for your response mate, the code above might work for email validation, but what about CompareValidator control, which can be used for date validation, do you have some example?

Comment: change the `regex` statement if You are not familiar with regular expressions I can post some example, just write the date format

Comment: in "dd-mm-yyyy" would be great.

Comment: many thanks @Mithrand1r, so we can say that Regex can be used for any kind of common validation right?

Comment: Regular expression is like a pattern. You write one and then check if the String You have is matching the pattern, in the result You get the `true` if match is found or `false` if there is no match. You can write regex for almost everthing you want